# Printing time() to a file results in binary characters

Tags: c++, time, binary, cout

I want to print the time to an output file. I'm using the following bit of code to do it:

```
time_t currentTime;
struct tm *localTime;

time( &currentTime );                   // Get the current time
localTime = localtime( &currentTime );  // Convert the current time to the local time
int Day    = localTime->tm_mday;
int Month  = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
int Year   = localTime->tm_year + 1900;
int Hour   = localTime->tm_hour;
int Min    = localTime->tm_min;
int Sec    = localTime->tm_sec;

output << "SimpleLD run at " << Day << "/" << Month << "/" << Year << " " << Hour << ":" << Min << ":" << Sec << std::endl;
```

Where output is the output file. I'm running the code on multiple processors, but having only the rank 0 processor write to a file. For some runs, (4,8,16 cores) this works correctly. But for others (32, 64 cores) this results in the output file printing:

```
00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\
```

And the file thinking it's a binary file, rather than a .txt file. Some higher core counts print correctly. What am I doing wrong? How do I get the time to print out correctly, no matter how many cores the code is running on?

Comment: How did you open the file `output` is connected to?

Comment: What effect would the number of cores have on the output here? Is `output` owned by a single thread?

Comment: I didn't think about that. This is an MPI only code so only 1 thread per core. I think every MPI rank is opening the output file even though only rank 0 writes to it.

Comment: Could you provide more context about how you are multithreading the code? Whether each variable lives on the stack and is unique to each thread or not is quite a big detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had every core opening the output file even though only 1 core was writing to it. When I had only the MPI rank that writes to the output file open it, the problem seems to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue probably stems from the fact that the `localtime()` function **is not** thread-safe.  It returns a pointer to a static buffer which may become damaged if other sources call `localtime()`.

There is a thread-safe implementation of `localtime()` called [`localtime_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) which is available on some systems.  If that is not an option, you need to make sure only one thread is calling or using the results of `localtime()` at any given point.

Comment: He could also make a local copy of the buffer.